# How can I extend this Ruby ActiveRecord model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-design, activerecord

I'm creating this little show scheduler thing.

I have the table shows, with `title:string` and `description:text`. I want to add days and times to the show (each show can have multiple days, and each day has their OWN times). How might I go about doing this?

I was thinking of making a times table. With the columns (`show_id`, `day`, and `time`). Then when listing the show, you search for times that meet that `show_id` and sort by day.

Any ideas, suggestions, etc. welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

You'd create the `Show` model with the following command:

```
script/generate model Show title:string description:text
```

Then you'd create the ShowTime model:

```
script/generate model ShowTime date:datetime time:datetime
```

Then, in your `show.rb` model file, you'd define a `has_many` relationship like this:

```
 has_many :showtimes
```

And in your `ShowTime` model file, you'd define a `belongs_to` relationship like this:

```
 belongs_to :show
```

Comment: I think your ShowDate and ShowTime models should include show_id:integer in order to make the relationship work? And shouldn't it be `belongs_to :show` (lower-case "s")?

Comment: Why would you separate the Date from the Time? Wouldn't it make more sense to just combine these into a single DateTime field? Then each show time can have a date and a unique time for that date, without needing to manage them separately.

Comment: Sorry if I might have confused you guys in my post, or maybe I'm misunderstanding.

But, wouldn't this require that I add each time and day specifically? (Like I add "9/13/10 5:30", "9/20/10 5:30", and "9/27/10 5:30"?)

I want to be able to just add the day of the week, and the time for that day.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me the simplest solution to this would be to use a single DateTime Object, since you can get the day and the time from a Time object.

`script/generate model ShowTime time:datetime

script/generate model Show title:string description:text showtime:references`

Then put in the belongs_to/ has many_associations that Jacob referred to.  I think having a separate model for the showtime would be better and allow for more flexibility.  You should also look into the strftime method on a Time object, to format the time to your liking.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why bother with ShowTime? Why not just add time:datetime to the Show model? It seems more like a property of show then its own thing

Comment: @Matt, the OP wants to be able to have many times associated with **one** `Show`, that's why.

Answer (score -1):

I think your idea is very reasonable (especially for someone who has no experience with programming). If you're interested in "Rails way" of implementing this, I would recommend checking `has_many` relationship in [the Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-association). (And I do recommend this guide in general, as it helped me a lot with Rails)